# Space in filename? file_put_contents

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352927/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated)

I am using a WordPress plugin on my WordPress site to upload a series of images. It always works fine, unless the image urls got spaces in them.
I tried using urlencode but I am still getting errors. This is the code where it breaks:

When I `echo` out `$img` it's

`"http://omodaimg.xcdn.nl/RM1000,1000/taupe-paul-green-sneakers-1157/PAUL GREEN/31024_1.png"`

without the quotes.

```
foreach ($imgs as $img) {                                                                   
$image_filename = wp_unique_filename($uploads['path'], basename(parse_url(trim($img), PHP_URL_PATH)));
$image_filepath = $uploads['path'] . '/' . $this->url_title($image_filename);
if ( ! file_put_contents($image_filepath, @file_get_contents(trim($img)))) {
    if (! get_file_curl(trim($img), $image_filepath)) {
        $logger and call_user_func($logger, sprintf(__('<b>ERROR</b>: File %s cannot be saved locally as %s', 'pmxi_plugin'), trim($img), $image_filepath));
        unlink($image_filepath); // delete file since failed upload may result in empty file created
    }
}
```

Is anyone seeing with I am not seeing? Any hints in the right direction are very much appreciated.

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/....
But I don't believe that got anything to do with it. This is the warning I get when get_file_curl() is called

Comment: @user67510 sounds like you should turn safe mode off..

Comment: If you don't want to turn off safe mode then this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction

Comment: Safe mode is off and open_basedir is commented out. I am on my own VPS by the way.

Comment: Also the function get_file_curl() is using the solution posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352927/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be more of a problem in your server configuration rather than problem in your code.

Try disabling safe mode in your php.ini file.

Comment: Safe mode is off and open_basedir is commented out. When I try a image without spaces in it, everything goes fine.