# curl with proxy not working properly

Tags: php, parsing, curl, proxy

I am using `curl` function to parse data from backpage.com and oodle.com.In backpage.com, I am using proxy, but it not working on client's server but it perfectly working on our server. But in the oodle.com proxy is not working. Is any other way to parse data from oodle.com? My code is,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$original_file = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In client's server it shows an error

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in
```

I am use `phpinfo();` to check the settings , the **safe_mod** option is off but **openbase_dir** have value. How can I fix this issue? Any one please help me.

Comment: Do you have access to php.ini? Just find open_basedir in php.ini and clear its value.  It's working as intended, the warning is quite clear.

Comment: Try taking a look at this helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352927/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated